Can using async/await in a razor page's OnGet cause unreliable loading of controls?
I switched the OnGet of my razor page to be async and I noticed some of my controls would no longer load reliably.
I have a kendo multiselect on the page and once I switched to async it only loads the list of options about 50% of the time. Controls that don't contain a list of options seem to load ok. I switched back to synchronous and everything loads reliably again. Is async/await not appropriate for use when fetching data from the DB to populate the page?
Here's the async version of my OnGet:
    public async void OnGet(int securityGroupId)
    {
        if (securityGroupId == -1)
        {
            SecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup();
            SecurityGroup.IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SecurityGroup = await DL.GetEntityByIdAsync<SecurityGroup, int>(securityGroupId);
        }

        RoleList = await DL.GetLookupListAsync<Role>();
        RoleList = RoleList.OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList();
    }

Here's the synchronous version:
    public void OnGet(int securityGroupId)
    {
        if (securityGroupId == -1)
        {
            SecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup();
            SecurityGroup.IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SecurityGroup = DL.GetEntityById<SecurityGroup, int>(securityGroupId);
        }

        RoleList = DL.GetLookupList<Role>().OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList();
    }

RoleList is: public List<DDL> RoleList { get; set; }
DDL is a class containing a string Id and a string Text;
Here's the async version of GetEntityById:
    public async Task<TEntity> GetEntityByIdAsync<TEntity, TId>(TId id) where TEntity : class, IIdentifiable<TId>, new()
                                                                   where TId : IEquatable<TId>
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();

        try
        {
            entity = await db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id.Equals(id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return entity;
    }

Here's the synchronous version:
    public TEntity GetEntityById<TEntity, TId>(TId id) where TEntity : class, IIdentifiable<TId>, new()
                                                       where TId : IEquatable<TId>
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();

        try
        {
            entity = db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id.Equals(id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return entity;
    }

Here's the async version of GetLookupList:
    public async Task<List<DDL>> GetLookupListAsync<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IDDLable
    {
        List<DDL> ddl = new List<DDL>();

        try
        {
            ddl = await db.Set<TEntity>().Select(lu => new DDL { Id = lu.DDLId, Text = lu.DDLText }).ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return ddl;
    }

Here's the synchronous version:
    public List<DDL> GetLookupList<T>() where T : class, IDDLable
    {
        List<DDL> ddl = new List<DDL>();

        try
        {
            ddl = db.Set<T>().Select(lu => new DDL { Id = lu.DDLId, Text = lu.DDLText }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return ddl;
    }

The multiselect is defined as:
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.SelectedRoles)
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .AutoClose(false)
            .Placeholder("Select Role(s)...")
            .BindTo(Model.RoleList))


don't believe you should be returning void and it should be OnGetAsync.... so try:   public async Task OnGetAsync(int securityGroupId)

How is RoleList being bound to the View Model?

@RossBush Via [BindProperties]

@browsermator I think you nailed it with the return type. I forgot about not returning void with async. Seems to be working now. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

you can answer your own question here.  Better to do that so that solution is clear.  Not real sure whether the OnGetAsync bit was necessary there?

Changing the return type of OnGet from void to Task resolved the issue. The Async suffix didn't have any effect, I believe it's just a matter of naming convention.
The function now reads:
    public async Task OnGetAsync(int securityGroupId)
    {
        if (securityGroupId == -1)
        {
            SecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup();
            SecurityGroup.IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SecurityGroup = await DL.GetEntityByIdAsync<SecurityGroup, int>(securityGroupId);
            SelectedRoles = SecurityGroup.RoleIdList;
        }

        RoleList = await DL.GetLookupListAsync<Role>();
        RoleList = RoleList.OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList();
    }


async void seems to be an evil thing where the reference to the Task is thrown away and the caller cannot control it properly. I had similar view where I had async void OnGet, which would throw an exception, but because the Task is missing, the webserver would completely crash and exit, and the developerErrorPage couldn't intercept the failure.
At this point, I think I need to set up som checks to make sure async void will never appear in my projects... Seems like it is only ever a catastrophy and something the compiler should probably even reject. I don't see valid uses for it
